# How can i use bootstrap4 cdn and mdbootstrap cdn on 1 site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

Im using mostly the mdbootstrap cdn for my site but i need also the regular bootstrap cdn for certain things on my site but for some reason when i use booth cdns my site is totally messed up.

You can view my site here
abusive-secretary.surge.sh

I want to make a card carousell which should display 3 cards at a time, but when i include the bootstrap4 cdn only 1 card is shown.

How can i fix this?

Comment: multiple cdn's will slow your site considerably, why would you need to do this?

Comment: because what i try to do isnt working with the mdbootstrap cdn but if i only use the bootsrap4 cdn my site is looking terrible

Answer (score 0):

MDBootstrap contains Bootstrap4. But some styles may be overwritten. Just tell us what you need to do and what is issue.